# Multiple AJAX onclick call works on only one item

Tags: ajax, onclick, jquery

So here is my HTML:

```
<div class='delete-item' name='filetest' ></div>
<div class='delete-item' name='anothertest' ></div>
<div class='delete-item' name='coolfile' ></div>
```

And my JavaScript

```
$(".delete-item").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "delete_item.php",
        data: "name="+$(this).attr("name")+"&dir=<?php echo $encodedDirectory; ?>",
        success: function(data) {
            refreshItemList();
        }
    });

});
```

So the code works but only for one item. Whichever one I click first works and the ajax call is completed succesfully. However clicking on another does not even call the function (I tried by logging it to the console and it wasn't even logging anything except for the first item.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using jQuery.live instead of bind:

```
$(".delete-item").live('click', function() {
```

When you do `$(".delete-item").click(...)` jquery attaches an event to all `.delete-item` elements on the page. But in `refreshItemList();` you replace them with new ones, and no event handler is attached to the new ones.

`jQuery.live()` attaches events on all elements matching `.delete-item` at the time you call it, and also `.delete-item` created after you call it.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect, now I understand the problem. When I called refreshItemList() it was reloading the list where the delete buttons were.